# Reversing the limits of an integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

While studying Advanced Engineering Mathematics (Stroud) book, I encountered with the following statement for reversing the limits of an integration:

$\int_0^{-\infty}f(t)dt=\int_0^{\infty}f(-t)d(-t)=-\int_0^{\infty}f(t)dt$

where $f(t)$ is an even function.

This means that $d(-t)=-dt$. Why it is like that and what does $d(-t)$ mean?

Edit:

After Tom's u-substitution reply I did the following:

$u=-t$ therefore $du=-dt$ and

$\int_{t=0}^{t=-\infty}f(t)dt=\int_{-u=0}^{-u=-\infty}f(-u)(-du)=-\int_{u=0}^{u=\infty}f(u)du$

I hope this is valid. Previous notation ($d(-t)$) was confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a $u$-substitution. Set $u = -t$ in the original integral, then $d(-t)$ means $du$.

Comment: But why $d(-t)=-dt$?

Comment: @i.ozturk If you do the $u$-sub with $u=-t$, then $du = -dt$, right?